# how to pass variable values from a block to a node in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to create a system where a php-filtered block will pass variable values to the current php filtered article (node). If I put the variables within the article the script works. If I put them in a block region right above the article (node), they don't work. I do not understand why my variables would not work since they are executed on the same page. There must be something Drupal is doing that is not letting my node php scripts access the php variables values from the block.

I initially did not want to explain why I am doing what I am doing because it would be too long, but I could if you think it is necessary. Hopefully I kept it simple enough to understand what I am after without all the other details.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try use functions instead

Comment: What do you mean by "put the variables within the article"? Within the node template file? In general, it sounds like a scoping issue. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php may also want to check out [template preprocess functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7)